# Quelle serait une façon plus élégante de formuler: « Pour ce que cet individu/homme a coûté, il apporte fort peu »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

*Voici la phrase en titre avec les informations manquantes (le nombre maximal de caractères était atteint)

Pour ce que cet individu/homme a coûté au système de santé, il apporte fort peu à la société/collectivité.

Autre proposition: Pour ce que cet individu/homme a coûté au système de santé, il rend peu service à la société/collectivité.

Précision: Il s’agit d’un système de santé public qui dispense des soins gratuits aux résidents.

C’est surtout la tournure « Pour ce qu’il » en tête de phrase qui m’embête, j’ai l’impression qu’elle manque d’élégance. J’ai cherché en vain par manque de temps à la reformuler sans recourir au groupe de mots « pour ce qu’ ».

Je vous remercie d’avance!

Comment: Pour ce qu’il a coûté au système de santé, il apporte fort peu à la société/collectivité. **n'est pas**: Pour ce que le système de santé a coûté, il apporte fort peu à la société. S'il s'agit du système de santé, la phrase ne va pas. On a l'impression qu'un homme a coûte cher au système de santé et que cette même personne a apporté peu à ladite société.

Comment: @Lambie C’est en effet le propos que je souhaitais exprimer, mais soyez sans crainte, il s’agissait seulement d’une idée qui m’a traversé l’esprit sans plus, elle ne vise personne en particulier, je vous l’assure.

Comment: Ok, je vois les changements. Il s'agit d'une personne...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Au regard de ce qu'il a coûté** au système de santé, le service rendu à la collectivité semble bien maigre.

Ou, suite à la mise à jour de la question:

> **Au regard de ce qu'il a coûté** au système de santé, ce qu'apporte cet homme à la collectivité semble bien mince.

Comment: Pas d'argot cette fois ;-)

Comment: Qu’entends-tu par « il », « le service rendu » ou « cet individu », « cet homme »…Bien franchement je suis dans le doute depuis que j’ai lu le commentaire que tu as laissé à Lambie… Mais j’admets d’emblée que je n’étais pas clair, ma question manquait de précision.

Comment: Pour ma part « il » renvoyait à un individu.

Comment: Si jamais ton « il » renvoie à « le service rendu », je vais devoir remettre en question mes capacités de compréhension…

Comment: Rien ne pouvait laisser supposer qu'il s'agissait d'un homme, mais ma réponse fonctionne quel que soit ce qui se cache derrière ce *il*.

Comment: Non, mon *il* renvoyait à quelque chose qui n'était pas exprimé, et j'avais supposé qu'il s'agissait de la gratuité.

Comment: …J’ai de la peine à suivre. Si ton « il » faisait initialement référence à « la gratuité », la phrase devient: Au regard de ce que la gratuité a couté au système de santé, le service rendu à la collectivité semble bien mince. Il me faut des éclaircissements!

Comment: Je cherche à comprendre ce que signifiait ta proposition avant la mise à jour.

Comment: Oui, c'est ça. Je supposais que tu mettais en parallèle le "coût de la gratuité" et le service rendu à la société de cette gratuité. Ce n'est pas très différent de ce que tu voulais dire. La seule nuance est que je comprenais qu'il s'agissait de tous les "résidents" alors que toi, tu ne pensais qu'à un seul d'entre eux.

Answer (score 2):

- En contrepartie d'un cout substantiel au système de sécurité sociale il n'offre qu'un maigre retour à la communauté.
- Son cout important, qui est  à la charge du système de santé, n'est pas à la mesure de ce que la communauté en tire.
- Étant donné  ce qu’il a coûté au système de santé, il apporte fort peu à la société/collectivité.
- Vu ce qu'il a couté au système de santé, il apporte fort peu à la société/collectivité.

Comment: Enfin, ce qu'il veut dire n'est pas clair du tout. On ne sait pas si c'est le gars ou le système qui a coûté cher etc.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette (TLFi) De la sorte (Syntagme défini) De cette manière. Synon. ainsi. // de la sorte trouvé dans la question : _de **cette** sorte_ (« de la sorte » dans ce cas-là est un anglicisme non incorporé dans le français (à moins qu'il ne s'agisse d'un anglicisme Canadien)).

Comment: Merci LPH pour la rectification!

Comment: @escarlateadamantine Il faut un exemple et un contexte complet ; alors je pourrai me faire une idée de si oui ou non ce que vous avancez est valide. Il ne faut pas confondre français et français canadien.

Comment: @escarlateadamantine Votre tour m'a tout l'air d'une construction obsolète ou qui n'a jamais eu cours puisqu'il est catégorisé comme appartenant à la langue de Molière ; voir ceci :  « de la sorte », https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Lexique_de_la_langue_de_Moli%C3%A8re_compar/-H1nbAktV_YC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22de+la+sorte%22&pg=PA142&printsec=frontcover .

Comment: @escarlateadamantine On doit ignorer cet article sur la langue de Molière qui parle chez cet auteur d'une substitution de l'article pour le démonstratif _ce_, _cette_, etc. ? Non, c'est clair, cela correspond à mon sens du Français: anglicisme de nos jours en Français. D'ailleurs il est clair que les anglicismes abondent dans le Français canadien.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127157/discussion-between-lph-and-escarlate-adamantine).

Answer (score 1):

Il a plus reçu du système de santé que contribué à la société.

Answer (score 1):

Peut-être dans l'autre sens ?

> Cet individu ne rapporte pas à la société le quart de ce qu'il lui a couté.

Comment: Bonjour ! Une bonne piste en effet de manière générale, vu que l'inversion rend ça plus lourd et moins clair il me semble.